# Why does anchors.fill does not work in a QML ListView's delegate's subviews, and what is a nice solution?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I encountered this:

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    model: ["Lorem","Ipsum"]
    delegate: Item {

        height: 20
        Text {
            z: 2
            text: modelData
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        Rectangle {
            z: 1
            color: "red"
            // this does not work:
            anchors.fill: parent
            // this works, but I have mixed feelings about it:
            // height: 20; width: listView.width
        }
    }
}
```

So, apparently, `anchors` do not work in a delegate's subitem (in this case, `Rectangle` is not displayed at all). I would like to understand the mechanism behind this. Also, I'd like to ask what is the preferred way to deal with this situation?
Thank You!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Item` has an `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` of zero, so making your `Rectangle` and `Text` fill it will result in them having no size as well.

There are two things wrong with your code:

1. The `ListView` has no `width` or `height` specified.
2. Your delegate has no `width` specified.

Here's one way of doing it correctly:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ["Lorem","Ipsum"]
        delegate: Item {
            width: listView.width
            height: textItem.implicitHeight

            Text {
                id: textItem
                z: 2
                text: modelData
                width: parent.width
            }

            Rectangle {
                z: 1
                color: "red"
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The [documentation of `ListView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#details) has more information.